# Why can we join same potential points in an electric circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I have a book that says that if 2 points have same potential in a circuit, then they can be joined together.
Here is an example given in that book regarding this.

[image]

Now, after joining those points, we can easily find equivalent resistance.
Please explain the reason behind it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Physics SE. What do you think the answer is? Please share with us your own attempt at answering, detailing your reasonings.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin The OP isn't asking for a problem to be solved here

Comment: @BioPhysicist It seems like the OP is asking a conceptual question, rather than how to do a calculation: namely, why can we combine two points in a circuit into one point when they have the same electric potential? I think it would be helpful if the OP provided their thinking on the matter.

Comment: To be honest, I am unable to think about the answer. Please provide your thinking on the matter. ( Also, what does OP mean?)

Comment: You write "On joining E & F and D & C..." That implies that in your top diagram they are *not* supposed to be joined. Is that what you mean? If so, then joining them will **not** give you an equivalent circuit.

Comment: @Philip Wood  yes, they are not supposed to be joined, and joining them may not give an equivalent circuit, but it gives the correct  equivalent resistance .

Comment: "but it gives the correct equivalent resistance ." I think not. If E & F, C & D are not joined the circuit resistance is $\frac 34 R$. If they are joined, the resistance is $\frac 14 R$.

Comment: If you check in Circuit simulation app then the correct answer is R/4

Comment: In your top diagram, if there are no links between E and F or C and D, then the top three resistors are connected in series between F and C. So the series combination (resistance 3$R$) is connected in parallel with the bottom resistor. That is not what your bottom diagram shows! The bottom diagram is correct when E and F are joined and C and D are joined. You are being misled by "Circuit simulation app" (whatever that might be).

Comment: Well, I think you are correct , thanks for your time.

Comment: If two points ARE at the same potential, then they can be joined by a wire without changing anything. That is because there will be no current through the wire, because there is no pd across it. So the wire has no effect. But in your top diagram, E and F are not at the same potential, nor are C and D!

Answer (score 1):

If the two points do have the same potential, no current is flowing from one point to the other, so you can join them without altering anything else in the flow of current. also you always can shorten a wire with no resistance to a point.

Comment: I think that if potential difference is zero and resistance is zero then it can have a finite value of current V=IR

Answer (score 1):

From a practical perspective, the conductors joining the resistances are supposed to be very small compared to them.

If we call $R_\epsilon$ the conductors resistance (ex: CD or EF), the equivalent resistance between points C and F is:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R+2R_\epsilon} + \frac{1}{R+2R_\epsilon} +\frac{1}{R+2R_\epsilon} }$$

As $2R_\epsilon << R$, the expression is very close to $\frac{R}{4}$

Comment: Please elaborate how you have written that equivalent resistance between C and F is 1/((1/R)+(1/(R+2Re))×3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what current and potential is. It would be better if I would explain you through the analogy of heat, as it is a more daily concept.

Potential is analogous to the temperature of a body, whereas current to the heat. Now, as you would probably have experienced, a hot coffee becomes cold and it eventually matches the temperature of the environment. Hence, heat flows from the coffee to the environment.

Similarly if you consider a wire with a potential difference of 0, in that case, according to the heat analogy, the potential (temperature) is constant, so will the current (heat) flow? No.

In a nutshell, this **ideal** wire does NOT affect the parameters or the components of the circuit.

Having said this, the asked concept can be implemented as a problem solving strategy to solve such circuits.

Comment: So if the current does not flow through ideal wire , then we can remove them (not join) and then calculate equivalent resistance but the answer will not come out to be correct